# OpenXML SDK - xls

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I got the OpenXML SDK to work with creating a .xlsx file. But is there anyway for it to create a xls file. Meaning, when it ask to open up an excel file, it only accepted .xlsx files and not .xls file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .xls (or BIFF) format is a proprietary binary format. The OpenXML format is just that...XML. The format was designed to be open for anyone to read, view, or modify the file contents without requiring Excel on the computer. To my knowledge, you cannot directly create BIFF-format Excel files using the OpenXML SDK.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a way to programatically convert the .xlsx file that was generated to .xls. We want to do this as most of our clients do not have .xlsx. Thanks

Comment: If you're not ready to move to .xslx, why are you using the OpenXML SDK? You could just use the Excel PIAs and not have to worry about conversion.